# SoapUI 5.0 - REST services - How to add securitytoken/object into requestheader?

Tags: rest

We're testing REST services and have created a new REST project in SoapUI 5.0.0
I've added endpoint but when I try to run the request as a 'GET' method I get:

400 (Bad Request): No securitytoken header information found in request header
No securitytoken header information found in request header

I've tried to add an SO in the parametertable as 'HEADER' but still no go.
Anyone knows?

-tosh

Comment: In SOAP webservices I have manually injected security headers. If you are using jdeveloper HTTP Analyzer you will get options to add security headers in both SOAP and REST webservices.

Comment: If that works then let me know, I can write an answer for it.

Comment: I managed to inject header, you can write an answer if you like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SOAP webservices you can manually injected security headers in the Request XML (make sure you use proper ns of the security policy).

If you are using jdeveloper HTTP Analyzer you will get options to add security headers in both SOAP and REST webservices
The Official SOAP UI has a getting started guide at

[Security Headers SOAP UI guide.](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html)

For Rest services you can use REST client 3.1 
and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2garScLQCEc) is the youtube video tutorial for using the tool.